# How to make the notification triggered after mojify applied Firebase Cloud Function Realtime Database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I want to make the notification display after mojify the text. Should it run simultaneously or triggered the mojify then notification?
How to make it happen? Thank you.

I'm using Firebase Cloud Function Realtime Database.

Notification functions using `onCreate`

```
exports.sendAdminGroupNotification = functions.database.ref('/adminChat/{adminChatUid}')
    .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
```

Mojify functions using `onWrite`

```
exports.emojify =
    functions.database.ref('/adminChat/{adminChatUid}/message')
        .onWrite(async (change, context) => {
            console.log("emojifying!");
            // Get the value from the 'text' key of the message
            const originalText = change.after.val();
            const emojifiedText = emojifyText(originalText);
        // Return a JavaScript Promise to update the database node
        return admin.database().ref("/adminChat/" + context.params.adminChatUid + "/").update({ message: emojifiedText });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in many ways. if you want the user to be notified only after the message is updated, then you can use the onUpdate() trigger

```
exports.sendAdminGroupNotification = functions.database.ref('/adminChat/{adminChatUid}')
    .onUpdate(async (snap, context) => { ... });
```

or simply call the sendNotification(...) function after you finish emojifying and updating the message:

```
exports.emojify =
    functions.database.ref('/adminChat/{adminChatUid}/message')
        .onWrite(async (change, context) => {
            console.log("emojifying!");
            // Get the value from the 'text' key of the message
            const originalText = change.after.val();
            const emojifiedText = emojifyText(originalText);
        // Return a JavaScript Promise to update the database node
        admin.database().ref("/adminChat/" + context.params.adminChatUid +"/")
        .update({ message: emojifiedText }).then(() => {
                console.log('emojified!');
                sendNotification(message);
        });
    });
```

For more on the subject [Sync, async, and promises](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions#how_promises_work_with_functions)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use callback on `update`

```
admin.database().ref("/adminChat/" + context.params.adminChatUid + "/")
.update({ message: emojifiedText }), function(error) {
  if (error) {
    // The write failed...
  } else {
    // Data saved successfully!
    //Send notification
  }
})
```

or use `onUpdate` trigger on the above reference instead of `onWrite`